# Strategy for table design for high write table/

Tags: database-design

I have a log table that log every action, click, etc a user takes on site.
So every second there may be hundred of thousands of entries waiting to be written.

I assume the database has to write one row at a time, it can't write multiple rows at the same time? So let's assume there are 500,000 entries that occured via 500,000 users logged in, now every second people are moving around so the database can process say 100,000 rows per second, the balance rows what happens to that?

Does it wait in the queue automatically or will the database give a write error or if the delay is 5 minutes, will it wait for 5 mins to write the record?

What technologies / strategies etc can i use for my extreme high write tables? One i know not to use FKs for these tables. What else?

My DB is MySQL and app is in codeignitor. All tables have innoDB engine.

Comment: What kinds of queries do you need on the log data, and how up-to-date do the results need to be?  You can append the log data to a file, for example, and import it to the database in batches.

Comment: It is an activity log table with live feeds like your fb feed. So as real time as possible. Because the plan is to move data from this table to an activity_log table which is denormalized for the user feed. So if this table is not up to date then other tables get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual logging probably doesn't need to be kept up to date real time I would utilize a message queue to send the "log" messages off to another process to write them.  That way when the utilization slows in the evening or over night the processing of records could eventually catch up.

Otherwise you could be in a situation where eventually your write will timeout and start blocking people navigating your website.

I'm not a MySql expert but if it works anything like SQL server the actual client sends a command to the server and if the command doesn't finish in a set amount of time the transaction times out and is rolled back.

Using a log file approach has the same problem as all threads will be trying to write to the same file and disk contention could be a problem.  If you put the queue on another server you could scale your solution.

Comment: The use of this data is for live feeds. user take some activity like comment on a photo or click link x,... this data is written to the log table. From the log table and other tables (session, object, account, etc) the data moves to a activity_feed table where the system reads to output to the activity feed. So if the log table doesnt write on time then the data wont move to the feed table that means no live feed.